# ubuntu 15.10 Startup screen flickering after login complete

Tags: upgrade, system-installation, updates, 15.04, recovery-mode

Today I upgraded my ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04 but during installation the system hung up and I was forced into a hardware reset. Now after startup, right after I enter my password, the screen flickers. I used a few shell commands in recovery mode in the hope of completing an upgrade:

```
mount -0 remount, rw / mount --all
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
update-grub
apt-get clean
```

and then rebooted.

how to recover the system/complete the incomplete setup update?

Comment: You already asked this at http://askubuntu.com/questions/622829/ .

Comment: I too did 15.04 to 15.10 and now screen uncontrollably flickers ... luckily  I did a backup onto Dropbox prior !   ... still ts my system

Comment: Are you using a laptop or something that has Intel integrated graphics?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method for login flash back:

1. Start the computer, Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to login the terminal
   $login:
   $password:
2. `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME`

This resolved my problem in ubuntu 15.04.

All the best.